# TYPO3 Fluid: How is it possible to use conditions and variables outside of <f:section> to make the layout dynamic?

Tags: templates, layout, conditional-statements, typo3, fluid

I try to change the layout which wraps each content-element by the definition from the backend. Unfortunately it seems that the variable for `{data}` is ONLY available inside of the `<f:section>` element. Even more problematic, the `<f:if>` condition ViewHelper has NO effect outsite of `<f:section>`, both `<f:layout>` statements are executed and only the last one is applied for rendering. That's not useful... and the documentation does talk only about ViewHelper inside of the Section. Do you know any other way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">

<f:if condition="{data.layout} == 101"><!-- if-condition has no effect here -->
  <f:then>
    <f:layout name="FullWidth" />
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
    <f:layout name="Default" />
  </f:else>
</f:if>

<f:debug>TEST1: {data.layout}</f:debug><!-- THIS DOES NOT SHOW UP AT ALL! -->

<f:section name="Main">
  <f:debug>TEST2: {data.layout}</f:debug><!-- Output is TEST2: 101 (integer) -->
  [...]
</f:section>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `f:layout` tag is read without rendering the template, so an if statement around it will not work. However, the name of the `f:layout` tag is rendered as a template, so you can use an inline if statement, like this:

```
<f:layout name="{f:if(condition: '{data.layout} == 101', then: 'FullWidth', else: 'Default')}" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a smart and easy solution! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the conditions into your TS, and use the settings for your layout name.

TypoScript

```
lib.layout = TEXT
lib.layout.value = Page
[globalVar = GP:print = 1]
lib.layout.value = Print
[global]
```

Template

```
<f:layout name="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.layout')}" />
```

This is how I did for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the value of your `data.layout` to build the name of the layout. in this way it is similar to the inline f:if-viewhelper.

```
<f:layout name="layout{data.layout}" />
```

make sure to handle unknown or empty values. Either with files with matching names or preparing a variable in typoscript with `.ifEmpty = default` or similar.

my normal solution for deciding the layout (I use the two fields `backend_layout` and `backend_layout_next_level` as they give the options of inheritance and individual override) :

```
    templateName = TEXT
    templateName.cObject = CASE
    templateName.cObject {
        key.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
        key.override.field = backend_layout

        #Default Template
        default = TEXT
        default.value = Unterseite

        pagets__startseite = TEXT
        pagets__startseite.value = Startseite

        pagets__katalogseite = TEXT
        pagets__katalogseite.value = Katalogseite

    }
```

---

A further way is to evaluate the layout inside the layout-file. depending on the layout value you can render specific sections or partials which build the complete template.
Here you have the option to use the layout value inline to decide the section/ partial, too.

```
<f:render partial="page-{page.layout}" />
<f:render section="section-{page.layout} />
```

Or you use `f:switch` or `f:if`-VHs.

---

as always:
**which solution is the best? it depends.**

you need to consider your special requirements to get the best solution.